# Why Right Outer Join is not supported in ksql?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

By going through this documentation https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html, i found that kql doesn't support right outer join, BUT WHY ?

Comment: Just flip left and right side and use left-outer join :)

Comment: work around is Ok....was just curious to know what are the reasons to not support right outer join @MatthiasJ.Sax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not been added yet.

The code is available and PRs are welcome if you'd like to add it: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/ or you can [search issues](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/) and upvote the one requesting it (or raise one if it doesn't exist already)